# how to save data that returns a cursor Android

Tags: android

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "

    + "title text not null,"
    +"location text not null, " 
    + "body text not null , "
    +" goaldate text not null , "
    +" absolutedate text not null , "
    +"currentdate text not null , "
    +"prio text not null, "
    +"done text not null, "
    +"category text not null, "
    +"timespent text not null, "
    +"pososto text not null,"
    +"father text not null);";

// fetch all tasks(tasks and subtasks)
public Cursor fetchTasks() { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER},null, null, null, null, null);

}

//fetch subtasks of a task, given the father's key
public Cursor fetchSubTasks(String id) { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + "'"+ id+"'", null, null, null, null);

}

//fetch a subtask
public Cursor fetchSubTask(String fid,String uid) { // tropopoihsh ths methodou wste sthn arxiki othoni na fainontai mono oi tasks

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + " '"+ fid +" '"+ " AND " + KEY_ROWID + " LIKE " + " '"+ uid +"' ", null, null, null, null);

}

          mCursor= mDbHelper.fetchTasks();//fetching all the tasks
          int numberoftasks= mCursor.getCount();
          this.mCursor.moveToFirst();
          int n,m;
          String id, idf;

          int columnIndex= 0;
          for(n=0;n<=numberoftasks;n++){

              id=this.mCursor.getString(0);//unique id of the current task

              mCursor=mDbHelper.fetchSubTasks(id);// fetching the subtasks with father_id=id

              String[] my = new String[mCursor.getCount()];

                if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
                {                       
                    for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++)
                    {
                        my[i] = mCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        mCursor.moveToNext();
                    }           
                }

            m=0;


            int subtasks=mCursor.getCount();

            int j;
            for(j=0;j<=subtasks;j++){

                  mCursor=mDbHelper.fetchSubTask(id, my[j]);// fetching each time the task with the unique id( from the array)
                                                             //and father_id=id

                  LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear); // fill a textview of the list with one more textview
                  list.removeAllViews();
                  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

               //   for (Music music : albums.get(position).musics) {
                      View line = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row, null);

                      /* nested list's stuff */

                      list.addView(line);
                  }

                m++;
          }

             this.mCursor.moveToNext(); 
         // }
```

I have a database with a table tha is filled with tasks. every task has a unique id and a father's id in order to achieve nesting. my problem is that i cannot save properly the data that the cursor returns and i get an arrayOutOfboundsException.
here is my code. thank you in advance

---

```
     private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "

    + "title text not null,"
    +"location text not null, " 
    + "body text not null , "
    +" goaldate text not null , "
    +" absolutedate text not null , "
    +"currentdate text not null , "
    +"prio text not null, "
    +"done text not null, "
    +"category text not null, "
    +"timespent text not null, "
    +"pososto text not null,"
    +"father text not null);";

  // fetch all tasks(tasks and subtasks)
public Cursor fetchTasks() { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER},null, null, null, null, null);

}

//fetch subtasks of a task, given the father's key
public Cursor fetchSubTasks(String id) { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + "'"+ id+"'", null, null, null, null);

}

//fetch a subtask
public Cursor fetchSubTask(String fid,String uid) { // tropopoihsh ths methodou wste sthn arxiki othoni na fainontai mono oi tasks

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + " '"+ fid +" '"+ " AND " + KEY_ROWID + " LIKE " + " '"+ uid +"' ", null, null, null, null);

}
```

here is my code @Sam. Main tasks appear on a list and the thing that i want to do is to fetch the subtasks of each task(multiple levels, each subtask can have subtasks) and show them in a kind of list.(create a particular textview with details for each task every time that a task has a subtask).thank you in advance for any help or idea.

Comment: Hehe, you forgot the code...

Comment: My guess is that your `mCursor.getCount()` = 0. I would try and check to make sure that your cursor is getting the desired data.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop, the error is in the for loop for sure:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      //do your thing
}
```

with this loop you don't care how many elements exist. If this still gives you an outOfBound exception, then you're not fetching the lines correctly.

Comment: I changed the outer for loop with your answer and i still get the exception. i thought that the problem was basically at the array and the way that the data are stored. i will check also the fetching.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem is that you are trying to use one Cursor for the work of two or three...

```
mCursor=mDbHelper.fetchSubTasks(id);// fetching the subtasks with father_id=id
```

This needs to be a new Cursor (and change the appropriate references):

```
Cursor cursorId = mDbHelper.fetchSubTasks(id);// fetching the subtasks with father_id=id
```

Otherwise your outer for-loop or cursor access will run out of bounds here:

```
for(n=0;n<=numberoftasks;n++){
    id=this.mCursor.getString(0);//unique id of the current task
```

**Addition**

I took a guess at what you are trying to do and modified your code. But I don't see where you are using the third Cursor that you fetched, so this won't be perfect but maybe you will see where you are going wrong:

```
// You only need to find this layout once and create one LayoutInflater
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear); // fill a textview of the list with one more textview
list.removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchTasks();//fetching all the tasks
long id;

int columnIndex = 0;
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // If this is a SQLite id then use:
    id = mCursor.getLong(0);
    //id = this.mCursor.getString(0);//unique id of the current task

    Cursor subCursor = mDbHelper.fetchSubTasks(id);// fetching the subtasks with father_id=id

    // Loop through the subCursor, I didn't see any need to save the temporary value in an array
    while(subCursor.moveToNext()) {
        Cursor timeCursor = mDbHelper.fetchSubTask(id, subCursor.getString(columnIndex));// fetching each time the task with the unique id( from the array)
        //and father_id=id

        //   for (Music music : albums.get(position).musics) {
        View line = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row, null);

        /* nested list's stuff */
        list.addView(line);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i dont think that i need new cursors every time that i fetch. the cursor takes a new result set.am i wrong?

Comment: In the first line of `for(n=0...` you are trying to loop through all the tasks one at a time, but you change the Cursor in the second line. So when you loop back to the start of `for(n=0...` to read the second task, you are now pointing at a very different Cursor...

Comment: It.does, but you are still using the first cursor to drive the loop.  When you change the visor you change the loop.

Comment: you are right.this time at least i avoided the force clause.the code run properly but i cannot get the subtasks of each task.any way thank you all

Comment: some posts were removed i think. i will describe what I wnat to do in case you have any better ideas than mine!with the outer loop i check every task of tha database table.then, I look for the subtasks of each task with the inner loop and show a row with some details in the layout. (something like a multilevel list)

Comment: Ok, please edit your database's schema (CREATE statement at least) into the question and the fetch methods.